# Using C++ libraries from C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have access to c++ source code and as default it compiles to static *.lib .

Is there a simplier way to do it than writing C++/CLI wrapper?

Comment: Did you google this first? Or even just search here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're going to have to write a C++/CLI wrapper as .lib isn't executable code.

Here's one example of how to do it: [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge/)

Comment: Its either wrap with c and  dllimport **or** C++/cli, not both.

Comment: My bad, been quite some time since I did this last.. Updated the post a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You can import exported functions using [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: You can't use DllImport on .lib files

Comment: He has the source code, so why cant he just make it a DLL. and put the C# project and C++ project in the same solution for more easy access.